# How to access non-singleton objects from a Jersey Resource?

Tags: java, jersey

In our company we work a lot with small Java applications as service in Windows. To be able to get status reports from these applications we use Jersey to output some JSON data.

To get the needed application data we currently setup the application as a singleton. From the  resource handler in Jersey we can access the object via it's static getInstance method.

Now we are upgrading the complete application landscape and have made some changes to our applications. One of the changes is that the applications are no longer singletons. Is there any other way of accessing the application object without it being singleton and without the handler being an inner class?

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
public class Main {
    protected int data; // a property which has to be accessible by 
                        // the jersey handler
    protected Closeable server;
    protected ResourceConfig resourceConfig;

    public Main() {
        // set the jersey handle
        resourceConfig = new DefaultResourceConfig(JerseyHandler.class);
        // start the jersey server
        server = SimpleServerFactory.create("http://0.0.0.0:" + port, resourceConfig);
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }
}

@Path("/")
public class JerseyHandler {

    @Path("status")
    @GET
    public Response status() {
        // how to access Main's getData() method from here without 
        // anything being a singleton or an inner class???
        int data = ????;
        Response.ok().entity(data).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should inject Main as dependency with Dependency Injection mechanism that is supported by Jersey. I use Jersey 2.12 and Google Guice 3.0 for the same purpose.

Example:

```
@Singleton
@Path("language")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class LanguageResource {
    private final LanguageService langService;

    @Inject
    public LanguageResource(LanguageService dateService) {
        langService = dateService;
    }
}
```

To configure the listener with custom Guice module:

```
        ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler();
        handler.setServer(server);
        handler.addEventListener(new ServletGuiceConfig());
```

Your Guice config could look like this:

```
public class ServletGuiceConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    protected static Injector injector;

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new ServiceConfig(), new ServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                bind(LanguageService.class).to(LanguageServiceImpl.class);
            }
        });
        return injector;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does indeed look like what I need. Thx! One last question: Don't you need to declare somewhere which instance of LanguageService should be injected?

Comment: @RickBrunken: I was interrupted. I updated my answer. Sure, your Guice configuration should be provided, I described how I do it for my server